# spanning tree implemented by a min priority queue

Tags: algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree

if it is executed on unconnected graphs what will it execute? I thought it won't execute since it is unconnected but since it is being implemented by min priority queue, will that affect the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would generate the MST for the component of the graph which the MST algorithm starts at, leaving the unconnected components untouched.

Comment: then how does being implemented by a min priority queue make a difference? will it affect a minimum spanning forest?

Comment: Is your pq used to run the Prim's algo?